# Simple lightbox with CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi I am trying to make a simple lightbox. I used css and very little jQuery for this. My code is as you can see below, but no matter which image I click, the last image I added opens. What is it that I overlooked? How can I get the image I clicked to open?

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lightbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a class="trigger">
        <img src="img1.jpg">
        <div class="lightbox">
            <img src="img1.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="trigger">
        <img src="img2.jpg">
        <div class="lightbox">
            <img src="img2.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
.trigger {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trigger img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.lightbox {
    /* Default to hidden */
  display: none;

  /* Overlay entire screen */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* A bit of padding around image */
  padding: 5em;

  /* Translucent background */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(".lightbox").toggle();
});
```

Comment: `$(".lightbox")` selects *all* elements of that class. You need `$(".lightbox").hide();` then `$(this).find('.lighbox').show();`

Comment: There is no such term as *"lightbox"*. it was a name of an ancient script which implemented the term ["modal" window.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

Comment: also, please edit the title to address the **specific problem** as it is too vague now

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question with the problem solved, so that those who want to have a simple lightbox in the future can benefit

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lightbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a class="trigger">
        <img src="img1.jpg">
        <div class="lightbox">
            <img src="img1.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="trigger">
        <img src="img2.jpg">
        <div class="lightbox">
            <img src="img2.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
.trigger {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trigger img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.lightbox {
    /* Default to hidden */
  display: none;

  /* Overlay entire screen */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  /* Translucent background */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).find(".lightbox").toggle();
});
```

You can use this simple lightbox just by editing the trigger class as thumbnail as you want